# Mysql search for exact number in field

Tags: mysql

in my MySql DB, i have column containing that kind of value

```
63  61  57  52  50  47  46  44  43  34  33  27  23  22  21  10  5   3   2   1
```

Those numbers are separated by tab.

Impossible to get the good result for a simple query that would aid something like this

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn = 63
```

I'm not sure if "=" is the good method, i've also tried LIKE, IN and even FIND_IN_SET

I need some help :)

Comment: yes, you need help. Help in storing your data properly

Comment: I Know this not the good way to store it... i've not build this DB, i simply need to make this query work... if possible :)

Comment: when people say they can't make another table, that is translated into "I don't feel like doing it"

Comment: You know what you are talking about saying so ....
Thanks anyway

Comment: what datatype are you using for that column?

Comment: you could use like operator, SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE '%63 %'

Comment: I think you need exact number match, and if i'm right then you have to first replace the tab or space to comma(,) and then use FIND_IN_SET. **i.e. SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE FIND_IN_SET(63, replace(`mycolumn`,"\t",","));**

Comment: while @KaushaMehta 's query may work, it's going to be slow. There is no substitute for proper table design.

Comment: @e4c5 This is not a proper way to store data, but they need solution any how so................

Comment: agreed @KaushaMehta but they are just prolonging the agony and wasting their time.